# Use sketch graph to state the number of solutions to the equation

Tags: calculus, roots, graphing-functions

[image]A curve has the equation

> $$y = -2x^2 +6x - 5$$

The completing square for the equation above is

> $$ y = -2\left(x-\frac32 \right)^2 - \frac12$$

Use the sketch graph, state the number of solutions to each equation

> $a)$ $|-2x^2 +6x -5| = 2$
>
> $b)$ $|-2x^2 +6x -5| = -3$

How do I determine the number of solutions?
I managed to find the turning point of the curve equation $ = \left(\frac32, -\frac12\right)$. There is a y-intercept at $(0,-5)$ and when I substitute $1 $ and $2$ into the curve equation, I will get $-1$ for both values of $x.$

Comment: "*Using a sketch of the graph*" - Did you successfully graph the function?

Comment: I note that you do not need a sketch for part *b*.

Comment: Hint:  abs(quadratic) will look either like a U or a W.  Which do you have, and why?

Comment: Yes, I managed to sketch it. The graph is a frowned curve below the x-axis. Just that I do not know how to determine the solutions for (a) and (b) from the graph....

Comment: Take three points on your sketch.  For instance, let one of them be $(a,b)$.  We are to graph the absolute value of the function, so we should replace this point with $(a, |b|)$.  To where are those three points moved by taking the absolute value of their outputs (second coordinates)?  Do you see where your parabola is sent by the absolute value?

Comment: @EricTowers I've added my sketch.. I substituted f(0) = -5, f(1) = -1 and f(2) = -1. What should I do next?

Comment: So taking absolute values on the function outputs takes $(0,-5)$ to $(0,5)$, takes $(1,-1)$ to $(1,1)$ and takes $(2,-1)$ to $(2,1)$.  What do you think the absolute values do to the rest of the graph?

Comment: @EricTowers The graph will be flipped upward above the x-axis and the minimum point would be (3/2, 1/2) with the other coordinates (1,1), (2,1)...??

Comment: How many points on that graph will have height (that is, $y$-coordinate) equal to $2$?  equal to $-3$?

Comment: @EricTowers I see.....For 2, there would be 2 solutions and 0 solution for -3 since the graph is above the x-axis... Thank you very much.

Comment: You have it the other way around.  You have graphed the quadratic -- not the abs(quadratic).

Comment: @Andrew Chin The sketch question is prior to the (a) and (b). But I got it anyway. Thank you.